# Tkinter Attribute Error in __getattr__

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, attributeerror

I've been trying to open up a Tkinter window to create a simple autoclicker, but I'm stuck on the initialization part.

```
class Application(Tkinter.Tk):

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()    

    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initalize()

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app = Application(None)
    app.title('clicker')
    app.mainloop()
```

When I run this with "python clicker.py" I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clicker.py", line 39, in <module>
    app = Application(None)
  File "clicker.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.initalize()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1899, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: initalize
```

Any ideas?

Comment: ``initalize`` is not the same thing as ``initialize``...  Also, ``Tk()`` is the root element; it has concept of 'parent' (and nothing in Tkinter that does have that concept would accept None).

Comment: didnt notice that typo, and it did the trick. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled your method name. instead of `initalize` write `initialize`.

Since you don't have a method called `initalize` you got an attribute error message.